# Calculate the RMSE of two dataframes with same lenght

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a dataframe (X) containing some missing values (20%), i decided to fill in the missing values using MICE imputation technique and have the complete dataset (Y) as a new dataframe. Now i want to check the accuracy using RMSE, is there a way to calculate the RMSE of entire dataframes instead of calculating RMSE on column by column basis. i tried the following

```
((X-Y)**2).mean(0)**0.5
```

Though it was able to handle the NAN values on X dataframe it however gives me RMSE for each column of the dataframe. I dont want the RMSE for each column, rather RMSE for the entire dataframe. Is there a way to achieve this in python?

I really appreciate your kind help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It helps other users to help you if you can provide your datatframes, or a small example demonstrating what you are trying to achieve. As code please, not as pictures, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Ok, here is more information to clarify my question. I have this dataset with 2593 rows and 8 columns. The dataset contains some missing values, I filled in the missing values using an imputation technique, I loaded the newly completed dataset into a new dataframe, Now, I want to check the accuracy using RMSE, is it possible to get the RMSE of entire dataframe rather than on column by column bases. Using this code

Comment: Here is more info to clarify my question. I have a dataset with 2593 rows and 5 columns. The dataset contains some missing values, I filled in the missing values using MICE, I loaded the newly completed dataset into a new dataframe, Now, I want to check the accuracy using RMSE, is it possible to get the RMSE of entire dataframe rather than on column by column bases. e.g.  Using this code ((X-y)**2).mean(0)**0.5 produced this output :
CO_1   2310.594133
CO_2   1869.410891
CO_3    0.000000
CO_4    9.356082
CO_5   7.875241
I want RMSE for the dataframe as a whole not for each column

Answer (score 0):

If X and Y have the same structure, you can use the underlying numpy arrays and `.flatten` them:

```
(((X.values.flatten()-Y.values.flatten())**2).mean())**0.5
```

Comment: Thanks so much Andre S for your help.  X and Y have the same structure, however, X contains some NAN values while Y does not contain any NAN value as i have imputed the NAN values on the Y dataframe. Your suggested solution gives NAN as the output when executed instead of giving the RMSE between X and Y

Comment: I think you can do `.nanmean()` to skip nans

Comment: Thank you so much @piterbarg, i'm working with python. when i used .nanmean(), I get this error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'nanmean'

Comment: ah sorry I think it needs to be ``(np.nanmean((X.values.flatten()-Y.values.flatten())**2)**0.5` see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html